# Convert short date format to ISO date without altering date

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I'm getting a specific date from a request in short date format and I am trying to change to iso format with the `Date()` constructor, but I want to change only the format, not the date. Is there a way in javascript to do this?

Request

```
const { data } = await axios.post(`${ur}`, body_object);
```

Response:
`"ReceivedDate": "26/12/2022",`

Format data

```
data.ReceivedDate = new Date();
console.log(data.ReceivedDate) // output: 2023-03-21T00:38:39.169Z
```

Expected output: `2022-12-26`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you're changing the `data.ReceivedDate` to a **new** `Date` instead. Instead, you need to do a bit of parsing with the `.split()` method to get the days, months, and years. From here, just put it in the format of full year-month-day. If all you need is the string, then this is sufficient. If you need the full `Date` object, then just pass it to the `new Date()` constructor.

Also, it is generally a bad idea to change the response object, so you'll want to create a different variable to hold it. Like this:

```js
const data = {ReceivedDate: '26/12/2022'}; // example data

const [days, months, year] = data.ReceivedDate.split('/');
const isoString = `${year}-${months}-${days}`;
console.log(isoString);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
let ReceivedDate;
ReceivedDate = "26/12/2022"

const splitDate = ReceivedDate.split("/"); // ["26", "12", "2022"]
ReceivedDate = splitDate[2] + "-" + splitDate[1] + "-" + splitDate[0];

console.log(ReceivedDate)  // 2022-12-26
```

Comment: Thank heavens for common sense. :-) Consider `let [d, m, y] = date.split(/\D/); let d2 = \`${y}-${m}-${d}\``.

Comment: Welcome, keep coding.